# Close popup page

Tags: javascript, html

How do I close a popup page? The page opens, but I can close it without refreshing the page.

```js
const chartDom = $("#main")
const seeResultsBtn = $("#seeResults");

function resultChatrs() {
  table.classList.add("invisible");
  title.classList.add("invisible");
  chartDom.classList.add("active");
}

seeResultsBtn.addEventListener("click", resultChatrs);
```

```html
<button id="seeResults">See Results</button>

<div id="main"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is the function resultChatrs?

Comment: _“but I can close it without refreshing the page”_ — Surely, you meant “can’t”, right?

Comment: What is `table`? Why isn't `seeResultsBtn` defined? Please see [ask] and provide enough information for us to help. None of this code seems related to a popup.

Comment: The opposite of [`add`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add) is [`remove`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove). So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Protip: Don't mix jQuery and plain JavaScript. It's just confusing. Use one or the other so the objects being acted on are alike.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return all to their previous state, something like this:

```
const chartDom = $("#main")

const hideResultsBtn = $("#hideResults");

function hideResultChatrs() {
  table.classList.remove("invisible");
  title.classList.remove("invisible");
  chartDom.classList.remove("active");
}

hideResultsBtn.addEventListener("click", hideResultChatrs);
```